# Pyspark split array of JSON objects column to multiple columns

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe in which one of the column is in below format:

[{key1: value1},{key2:value2}, {key3:value3}, {key4:value4}]

Lets say it as ColumnY as below:

| ColumnY |
| --- |
| [{key1: value1},{key2:value2}, {key3:value3}, {key4:value4}] |

I would like to convert it into columns of the dataframe where column name is keyX and its contents are valueX where X=[1,4] as below:

| key 1 | key 2 | key 3 | key 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 |

I have tried some solutions but they didn't work. Request you to share any ideas or solutions if you have. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That is a very badly formatted JSON without any quotes, but you can still parse it by brute force:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.selectExpr("""
    explode(
        transform(
            split(ColumnY, ','), 
            x -> str_to_map(regexp_replace(x, '[\\\\[\\\\{ \\\\]\\\\}]', ''), ' ', ':')
        )
    ) as col
""").select(F.explode('col')).groupBy().pivot('key').agg(F.first('value'))

df2.show()
+------+------+------+------+
|  key1|  key2|  key3|  key4|
+------+------+------+------+
|value1|value2|value3|value4|
+------+------+------+------+
```